# Listing the contexts for a session and updating the values of the parameters of the contexts

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm planning to use the dialogflow_v2 SDK of python, I have an intention of resetting the parameters in a context,
let me explain the scenario -  I have an intent which accepts start and end date one by one, as I'm using the webhook slot filling, I would like to validate if the end date falls after the start date and if condition fails, I would like to get the start and end date again with new values after showing the slot filling response.

Is this possible using the v2 SDK?

I have checked the usage code given in 
https://github.com/googleapis/dialogflow-python-client-v2/blob/master/dialogflow_v2/gapic/contexts_client.py
to list the contexts and update the contexts.
I have also followed https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-auth-setup to set the key.json for authentication. I used a service account with the role as API client and ADMIN to generate authentication key JSON.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you update your question to clarify exactly where you're trying to do this? Are you doing this in a webhook fulfillment (when a user has sent something to Dialogflow, and Dialogflow has sent a request to your code), or are you using Python to call Dialogflow to process input?

Comment: Sorry Sairaj, I was too busy to look at this.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a use case where I wanted to set the parameters as mentioned in the above question to validate the parameter values captured in the intent and resend it.
I found a way to do it by using the events in the dialog flow, you need to actually attach an event to the intent and update it with the validated parameters.

You can refer the following link, 
https://dialogflow.com/docs/events/custom-events

Hope, It will help others who are facing this issue.

Thanks a lot.